# Why number of distribution keys cannot exceed 4 in Netezza

Tags: ddl, netezza

I am trying to create table with 5 distribution keys.

```
create table WHDEV_RAW.DWADMIN.TEMP_WRK_TABLE
( 
    LOC_ID  INTEGER NULL,
    TRANSACTION_TYPE    NUMERIC(2) NULL,
    TRANSACTION_DATE    DATE NULL,
    TRANSACTION_TIME    NUMERIC(6) NULL,
    SKU_ID  VARCHAR(25) NULL,
    REF_NUM VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    PO_NUM  NUMERIC(8) NULL,
    ADJUST_QUANTITY NUMERIC(10,4) NULL,
    UOM VARCHAR(25) NULL,
    ROW_INSERT_TMS  TIMESTAMP NULL 
) 
DISTRIBUTE ON (TRANSACTION_DATE,TRANSACTION_TIME,SKU_ID,REF_NUM,PO_NUM)
```

Got error: org.netezza.error.NzSQLException: ERROR:  Number of distribution keys cannot exceed 4. It is impossible to create table with greater than 4 distribution column or do we have any solution?

Comment: Did you resolve your DDL issues?

Comment: I solved without creating 5 distribution key.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is ‘it very rarely makes sense’

The distribution key has two purposes, both are for performance and scalability reasons (prioritized according to my personal experience):

1. even distribution of data
2. reduced redidstribution of data at join-time - co-located join is the best here...

The first is most efficiently achieved by random distribution.
The last requires that:

A. You join on ALL the involved distribution columns, on BOTH tables in your SQL statements.

B. All distribution columns appear in the same order on BOTH tables.

C. The data types are the same on both tables for the join columns.

As you can imagine, point A and B become less and less likely the more columns you have in the distribution key...

Furthermore: I see you consider distributing on ‘time’. I can with 99% certainly say: never do that, but put one of them in the ‘organize on’ portion of your DDL.

Please write back if you need further clarification.

Comment: Thank you @Lars G Olsen for your answer. Actually this problem occurred in ODI (Oralce Data Integrator) while selecting 5 unique key in Data Model. I have solve this problem in my own way.

Comment: Sound like a bug: a unique key has nothing to do with a distribution key. I realise that they MAY be the same at times, but that is the same as saying that because a man is drunk, you can deduct that all male are alcoholics. The oracle tool probably doesn’t have the right options built into it.